Install pods got a warning hermes-engine has added 1 script phase
When I installed pods for the first time I got a warning in the terminal:
[!] [Codegen] warn: using experimental new codegen integration

[!] hermes-engine has added 1 script phase. Please inspect before executing a build. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#script_phases` for more information.


But not get a warning hermes-engine has added 1 script phase when do pod install --repo-update.
The app starts and runs on the simulator/device.
Can anyone explain what is it and should I fix it?

I had the same case and I found the answer in the documentation.
In my case, I had upgraded React Native from 0.74.2 to 0.75.4
and when I run the command:
bundle exec pod install

I got the message a warning message:
[!] hermes-engine has added 1 script phase. Please inspect before executing a build. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#script_phases` for more information.

The docummentation said to add
:hermes_enabled => true

in the file ios/Podfile
and also
hermesEnabled=true

in the file android/gradle.properties
So, after doing that I got this in my Podfile.lock:

